# How can I toggle the color of the background without Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I like to toggle the background color of the body by clicking a button with the help of CSS only. Is there any way to do it.

```js
function changeColor(color) {
                document.body.style.background = color;
            }
            
            function color() {
                changeColor('yellow');
            }
```

```html
<button onclick = "color()">
            Click here
</button>
```

Comment: as long as you're using onclick, this is kind of a catch-22

Comment: CSS can only be used to style the selected element.
You cannot style background based on button with CSS only.

You need JavaScript for this

Comment: CSS doesnt have the facility to allow you to go 'back up' the document to influence the styling of the parent element or other ancestors.

Comment: By *toggle* you mean switching between two different colors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Pure CSS solution would be to use a `checkbox` and create an another `div` with desired color. Then using `:checked` selector, you can check if `checkbox` is checked, and change `display` property of `div` according to it.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  background-color: white;
}

.bg{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.toggle:checked + .bg{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of JavaScript to change the color. Using class names is a good idea. So, you can use the toggle function on the classList of the body element to achieve this.

```js
document.getElementById('toggle_bg').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('yellow');
});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: lightyellow;
}

body.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle_bg">Click here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually change the background color of the body element itself using only CSS. CSS does not provide a way of influencing parents/ancestor elements, only siblings and children. However you can make it look as if you have a way.

It cant be done with button elements, but it can be done with input elements of type radio - that way you can have several 'buttons' allowing the user to select a different color.

In this snippet the radio inputs have a pseudo after element when it is focused. This pseudo element takes on the height and width of the viewport and is positioned absolutely. The button itself has no explicit positioning so the pseudo element gets positioned relative to its nearest ancestor that has a position and in this case it's the body element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
input:checked::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: var(--bg);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
<form>
<input type="radio" style="--bg: red;" name="color"/>Red
<input type="radio" style="--bg: blue;" name="color"/>Blue
</form>
</body>
```